# What is difference between hosted and non-hosted feature layer in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, hosting

When I add a slpk to ArcGIS Online there is an option if I want to host it as a hosted feature layer but this applies to 2D feature layers as well.

What is the difference between a hosted feature layer and a non-hosted feature layer?

[image]

Comment: Here you have an entry about the same doubt "What's the difference between a Feature Layer (hosted, view) and a Feature Layer?": https://community.esri.com/thread/190953-whats-the-difference-between-a-feature-layer-hosted-view-and-a-feature-layer